# How can I prove that a set of real numbers always have a minimum?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory

If I take a set of real numbers, say $S$, can I always prove that there is a number $n^*$, contained in the set $S$, which for all other $n$ in that same set, $n^*\leq n$ always holds?

I guess this is not always possible, but in which cases is it possible and how could I do it?

Comment: It clearly isn’t always possible: what if $S$ is the set of strictly positive real numbers?

Comment: I expected that, but in which cases will it be possible? And how would I do it?

Comment: What sort of conditions are you looking for? If $S$ is compact, for instance, you can always do it.

Comment: I was actually searching for the axiomatic properties of the real numbers that cause this behaviour.

Comment: If the set is closed is bounded below, you may conclude that it has a minimum. For your interest: every subset of the integers that is bounded below has a minimum; there is no need to check "closedness", whatever that would mean.

Answer (score 5):

It always has an infimum (if it is bounded below), but in general not a minimum. When the infimum is an element of the set, then the set has the minimum

Answer (score 1):

Take $S=\Bbb R$, such number would have to be smaller than any real number. Clearly this is impossible.

The real numbers are ordered densely. This means that between every two numbers there is a third one. it follows that if $x$ is smaller than all the numbers in $S$, either $x\in S$ or there exists $y$ such that $x<y\leq S$ (where $y\leq S$ means that $y\leq s$ for all $s\in S$).

It is true that in the real numbers if $S$ *has* a lower bound then it has a maximal lower bound. In the case of $S=\Bbb R$ there are no lower bounds at all. But in the case, for example, of $(0,1)$ every non-positive number is a lower bound, and $0$ is the maximal.

Note that if $x$ is the maximal lower bound of $S$, and $x\in S$ then $x$ is the **minimum** of $S$.

Sadly, there is no "general" characterization of sets which have a minimal element, except the tautological equivalence, $S$ has a minimum if and only if $S$ has a minimum.

The reason is that there are "too many" sets which have minimum, and "too many" that don't.

Comment: Okay, that's a counter-proof, but in which cases is it possible to prove? And how would I do it?

Answer (score 0):

From one axiomatic point of view $\langle\Bbb R,\le\rangle$ is a *complete* linear order. This means that if $S\subseteq\Bbb R$ has a lower bound with respect to $\le$, it has a *greatest* lower bound, or *infimum*, $\inf S$. However, $\le$ does not *well-order* $\{x\in\Bbb R:\inf S\le x\}$, so there is no assurance that $\inf S\in S$. In general that will depend very heavily on the specific set $S$. For instance, as I mentioned in the comments, $\inf S\in S$ whenever $S$ is compact. Indeed, $\inf S\in S$ whenever there is some $u>\inf S$ such that $[\inf S,u]\cap S$ is compact, but even this is far from being a necessary condition: it is not satisfied by the set of non-negative rationals, though that set plainly has $0$ as its least element.